# Delete button in each sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following VBA to insert a button in each sheet:

```
Sub Insert_Button_in_each_sheet()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
    b.Select
    Dim Button_01 As Button
    Set Button_01 = b.Buttons.Add(423.75, 0, 48, 15)
    Set Range_Button_01 = b.Range("B1:C5")
    Selection.Name = "Button_01"
    With Button_01
    .Top = Range_Button_01.Top
    .Left = Range_Button_01.Left
    .Width = Range_Button_01.Width
    .Height = Range_Button_01.Height
    .Text = "Button_01"
    End With
Next b
End Sub
```

All this works fine.

---

Now, I want to delete this button in each sheet using this VBA:

```
Sub Delete_Existing_Button()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
    b.Select
    b.Shapes("Button_01").Delete
Next b
End Sub
```

However, when I run this code I get `runtime error 5`.

What do I need to change in my code to make it work?

Comment: Try adding `Button_01.Name = "Button_01"` to your Insert code.  See if the delete code works then

Comment: What makes you think your button has that name ? `SelectionName =...` never use `selection`except for a good reason (and they are very rare)

Comment: You are naming the worksheet instead of the button. That's why you should avoid using `.select` and `.selection` and use explicit references to your objects instead. Furthermore, if you want your code to be consistent, since you used the `.buttons` collection in the first sub, you should use it in the second one as well instead of using the `.shapes` collection. It will work both ways but for the sake of consistency I would use only one of two.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your additional infos regarding the select method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option A:** Add the following line to the insert code:

```
Button_01.Name = "Button_01"
```

**Option B:** Change the delete code to the following:

```
For Each b In Worksheets
    b.buttons.Delete
    'or
    'b.buttons(1).delete
Next b
```